# Given F is Galois over E and E is Galois over K and a splitting field condition is given

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, separable-extension

Consider the following problem: This question  is from Thomas Hungerford Section 3 Problem 15.

> If F is algebraic Galois over K, then F is algebraic Galois over E, where E is an intermediate field.

Is " algebraic Galois " here algebraic and Galois.

I tried it by assuming that it is algebraic and Galois. So, if F is algebraic over K then F is algebraic over E as $K\subset E$. But If F is Galois over K then $Aut_K F = K $.  Now by the definition of $Aut_K E$ and as $E \subset F$ if an element of F is not fixed then clearly any element of E will not be fixed.

Is the proof correct?

(b) If F is Galois over E, E is Galois over K and F is a splitting field over E of a
family of polynomials in K[x] then F is Galois over K.

From the given condition of splitting I can deduce that F is galois over E but that is already given. SO, I am not able to deduce anything in this part and help is needed.

abstrac

Comment: If $F/K$ is Galois, it does not mean that $Aut_K(F)=K$. What *is* true is that the fixed field of $F$ under all of $Aut_K(F)$ is $K$.

Comment: Galois extensions are usually defined to be algebraic. So saying _algebraic Galois_ seems redundant. Just to be clear, what is your definition of a _Galois_ extension?

Comment: @Leo Let F be an extension field of K such that the fixed field of the galois
group $Aut_K{F}$ is K . Then F is said to be  Galois extension of K.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is essentially based on the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, which states that there is a bijection between intermediate field between $F$ and $K$ and the subgroups of $Gal(F/K)$, given that the extension $F/K$ is algebraic Galois.

a) Let $F/E/K$ be the intermediate field and let $\Phi: E\mapsto Gal(F/E)$ be the bijection.

b) Let $H$ be a subgroup of $Gal(F/K)$ and let $\Psi: H \mapsto F^H$ be the inverse mapping of $\Phi$.

Then suppose $F/E/K$ is intermediate field, then

c) $\Psi\circ\Phi(E) = E$

since $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are inverses. Then combine a) b) c) we know that $E=\Psi\circ\Phi(E) = \Psi(Gal(F/E))=F^{Gal(F/E)}$. This shows that $F/E$ is Galois.

Comment: you didn't answered part (b). Can you also help with that?

Comment: @Henri Davii Can you please tell what exactly you mean by symbol " F/E/K"?

Comment: How is the condition "algebraic extension" used in your proof?